# Change audio volume on the right device

Tags: audio, alsa, usb-audio

I'm trying to change the master output volume of my USB DAC (PCM 2704). 
When doing

```
aplay -L
```

I get:

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=ALSA
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=ALSA
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Default Audio Device
default:CARD=DAC
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=DAC
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=DAC,DEV=0
    USB Audio DAC, USB Audio
    Front speakers
...
```

but when trying `amixer`, I only have:

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback 0 [96%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

**How to change volume of the USB DAC? And first, how to select the USB DAC device in `amixer -c` ? I don't know if `amixer -c 0`, `amixer -c 1`, ...** *(None of them seemed to work)*

Comment: Does `aplay -l` give more useful output (i.e., the actual numeric device IDs that you are looking for)?

Comment: @dhag Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/v4xAArWx

Answer (score 1):

Finally doing

```
alsamixer
```

and using <kbd>F6</kbd> to select the right soundcard did the job!